# Problems installing Pip Cryptography in Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, cryptography

I am trying to install cryptography, but I am seeing a bunch of problems.
For some reasons there seems to be some dependency to my Visual Studio application and it tries to initiate some build process from there?!

> pip install cryptography
> Collecting cryptography
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/ac/552fc8729d90393845cc3a2062facf4a89dcbe206fa78771d60ddaae7554/cryptography-3.0.tar.gz
> Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
> Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
> Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography)
> Installing collected packages: cryptography
> Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
> Complete output from command c:\python38\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\daw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jxm0knmz\cryptography\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\daw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2sjuum9y-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography
> copying src\cryptography\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography
> copying src\cryptography\fernet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography
> copying src\cryptography\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography
> copying src\cryptography_*about*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography
> copying src\cryptography_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat_der.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat_oid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509\certificate_transparency.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509\extensions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509\general_name.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509\name.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509\ocsp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509\oid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> copying src\cryptography\x509_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\x509
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\cmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\constant_time.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hashes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\keywrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\poly1305.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\aead.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ciphers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\cmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ed25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ed448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\encode_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hashes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ocsp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\poly1305.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x509.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl_conditional.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ed25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ed448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\x25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\x448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\aead.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\algorithms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\modes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\concatkdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\hkdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\kbkdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\pbkdf2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\x963kdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\pkcs12.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\ssh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\hotp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\totp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
> copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
> running egg_info
> writing src\cryptography.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to src\cryptography.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing requirements to src\cryptography.egg-info\requires.txt
> writing top-level names to src\cryptography.egg-info\top_level.txt
> reading manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> no previously-included directories found matching 'docs_build'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.travis'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.github'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching 'rtd-requirements.txt'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
> writing manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> running build_ext
> generating cffi module 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_padding.c'
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
> generating cffi module 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_openssl.c'
> building '_openssl' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python38\include -Ic:\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release_openssl.obj
> _openssl.c
> build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release_openssl.c(546): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Does anyone have an idea what goes wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The real error seems to be: `Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h'`.

You seem to be missing the OpenSSL development libraries. [According to the documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/):

```
C:\> \path\to\vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
C:\> set LIB=C:\OpenSSL-win64\lib;%LIB%
C:\> set INCLUDE=C:\OpenSSL-win64\include;%INCLUDE%
C:\> pip install cryptography
```

Comment: I tried this, but it also failed. I ended up downgrading python to 2.7 and got it to work.